# "equipment" vs. "gear"

Tags: discussion, tag-naming

As far as I understand the words `[gear]` and `[equipment]` both refer to... well, the equipment. If this is the case and there is no difference in meaning that I miss, I would suggest using only one of them. Usage standings as of writing this:

- `[gear]` vs `[equipment]` - 3  - 10
- `[gear-recommendation]` vs. `[equipment-recommendation]` - 7 - 10

(there is also one question tagged `[used-equipment]`. I would personally vote for `[equipment]`, not only because it is already more use, but also because (in my opinion) it feels more "correct".

Comment: I went ahead and retagged the "gear" questions to the "equipment" counterparts.

Comment: "gear" has been set up as a synonym of "equipment".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I vote for *equipment*. It's more specific and appears to be dominant already.

Answer (score 0):

I think `equipment` generally refers to specific camera items, like body, lenses, filters, etc. I think the term `gear` is a bit broader, and can refer to things like camera bags or backpacks, hides, etc. I would have to read each of the posts that use gear and equipment tags to see if the usage was appropriate.

EDIT:

After reading all of the questions that use these tags, I would say all of them refer to camera equipment. I would agree, we could retag all the `gear` tags as `equipment` tags.